# Fill in zero values only in the center of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm working with a rasterio raster that I've 'read' into python, so it is now a numpy array. The outer edge of the np array are all zeros, and the interior are all ones, except, in the midst of the ones are occasional zeros, see the example array below. I want to leave all the zeros on the outside of the array alone (i.e. keep them zeros), but want to convert the zeros that are completely surrounded by ones (i.e. the zeros in the middle of the donut of ones) to one. However, I'm not really sure how to start.

Current array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Goal array:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: I have not used a slice before! Relatively new python user unfortunately.  Is there a way to slice based on surrounding values in the array?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Neither of the two duplicates seems to be about an approach that answers OPs problem algorithmically...

Please reopen I have a really good solution using a scipy method...

Comment: Ooo, I would love your answer :)

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I've misread - I didn't notice the other zeroes in the goal, and thought it was just about filling the middle of the array with 1s. However, you still need a more precise rule about how the 1s should be filled in. What if there is a larger region of all zeros, for example?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel & @ Sash Sinha. Thank you for sharing --> I'll look at the scipy option. And agreed, Karl, it is good to have a rule about how the ones should be filled in. In this case, if the region of 0s is totally surrounded by ones, regardless of size, it should be filled in with 1s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import binary_fill_holes

arr = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

filled_arr = binary_fill_holes(arr).astype(int)

print(filled_arr)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: No worries :) I could have described it a little more clearly too